# Handling popup window with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

I have the base page which has a button for "Add Link", upon click you get a popup window. The popup window has a form field to enter the link. Once the link is entered, I would like to refresh the base page - the base page should no more be "Add Link" but changed to the hyperlink entered in the popup window.

I am new to Javascript and html. I have by far managed to create a button on the base page and on click displays a popup window with form field for the link. However I am unable to refresh the base page with the new link.

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Add Link</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    prompt("Please Enter the Link"); 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the following will do is every time the button is hit, the prompt is shown, and once that prompt closes the script will add a new `<a href=value>New Link</a>` tag to the `demo` div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Add Link</button>
        // This needs to be a 'div' so it can have elements inside it.            
        <div id="demo"></div> 
        <script>
            var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
            function myFunction()
            {
                // Stores the value from the prompt() in the variable 'value'
                var value = prompt("Please Enter the Link"); 
                var link = document.createElement('a'); // Create an <a> tag
                link.setAttribute('href', value); // Set the link's URL to the value.
                link.innerHTML = "New Link"; // Set the link's display text.
                demo.appendChild(link); // Add the link to the demo div.
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hopefully the comments explain how it works, if not just ask here :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Could you please let me know how to remove the "Add Link" Option on the base page once the new link has been added?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add Link</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var url = prompt("Please Enter the Link"); 
    window.location = url;
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/douglasloyo/rtghQ/
the only value that is acceptable in js fiddle is going to be http://jsfiddle.net/

Cheers

Comment: Hi Douglas, I do not want to go to the link I added after adding. I want the link to be displayed in place of "Add Link" as "New Link"

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some way to store the link on the server; refreshing the page will cause everything to be re-executed, and you can't really dynamically alter the html file from itself. Something like django with a postgresql database is pretty easy to set up, but that's beyond the scope of your question.

That said, if you're okay with having the link not survive when the page is refreshed, you can use a text area instead of a prompt. Here's an example if you have jQuery:

```
<head>
<script>
$(function() {
$("#addLink").click(function() {
    var linkStr = document.getElementById("linkInput").value;
    $("#linkArea").html("<a href=" + linkStr + ">Your link</a>");
});
})
</script>
</head>

<span id="linkArea">
    <input id="addLink" type="submit" value="Add Link: ">
    <input id="linkInput" type="text" value="(enter link)">
</span>
```

Here's a jsfiddle to try it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/tRcUp/

Oh, and generally you should put scripts in the head tag.